# want to run docker file in windows machine

Tags: docker

Team mate sent me docker file - zipped one. I want to run it in my machine. I am using windows 10 64bit machine. Do I need to unzipped file first? I am new to docker. Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to unzip the Dockerfile and place it in a folder. You also need to setup Docker For Windows which can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/docker-for-windows/install/

After setting up, start docker and use

> docker build command

in the folder where you placed the Dockerfile to build the image.

Comment: it is giving me error saying : unable to prepare context: context must be a directory:

Comment: Can you tell me what exact command are you running? It might usually be an error with where your Dockerfile is and where you are running your build command.

Comment: So i have a file in x folder inside downloads folder. I open the x folder through command prompt and hit docker build <filename>.

Comment: file type it is showing file type. so i dont know what to give file extension. should we give file extension? Sorry for dump questions but please help.

Comment: You don't need to give filename as long as the name is 'Dockerfile'. Just run 'docker build -t <imagename> . ' in the x folder where the file is.
If the file is under a different name, then run 'docker build -t <imagename> -f <filename> .'
You can refer: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

Comment: My file name is export-sql-server. so how it will be? what is imagename exactly?